# How to set growing feature for a table?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table in `manageemployee.xml` as:

```
        <Table id="employeesTable"
                    growing="true"
                    growingThreshold="100"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    class="customtable">

                     <columns >
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="EMPLOYEE ID"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="EMPLOYEE NAME"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="DEPT"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="STATE"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="DISTRICT"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="CITY"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="ADDRESS"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column>
                             <Text text="ACTIONS"/>
                         </Column>
                    </columns>

        </Table>
```

All the data to the table is from an AJAX call and then `setdata` and `setmodel` and binding items to column list

May I know how to have growing feature for this table? How can I make my `contoller.js` code ?

`controller.js`:

```
var _this = this;
var searchFilterData = {};
        var searchdata = {};

        _this.searchFilter={};
            searchFilterData.index = _this.index;
            searchFilterData.numberofRecords = _this.numberofRecords;
            searchFilterData.empname=empname; //i used this for pagination
var listtable = this.byId("employeesTable");
var url = '*****';

            var aData = jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(_this.searchFilterData),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    _this.searchdata = data;

                },
                error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data)
                }
            });


var columnListItem = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                        cells: [

                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{empid}" }),
                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{empname}" }),
                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{department}" }),
                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{state}" }),
                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{district}" }),
                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{city}" }),
                            new sap.m.Text({ text: "{address}" }),
                             new sap.m.HBox({
                                items: [

                                    new sap.ui.core.Icon({
                                        src: 'sap-icon://edit',
                                        tooltip:'Edit',
                                        press: function (oEvent) {
                                            var rowobject = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();
                                            sessionStorage.setItem("empid", rowobject.empid);
                                            _this.getRouter().navTo("editemployee");
                                        }
                                    })

                                    ]
                                     })

                        ]
                    });
                    listtable.bindItems("/employeedata", columnListItem, null, null);
```

I am looking for growing feature for the table, I am able to do pagination for the same table but how to set the growing feature?

Answer (score 2):

Add your data binding. Lets assume your model is called "" (no name, default in most cases). Alter your xml like this:

```
<Table id="employeesTable"
                    items="{/MyExampleCollection}"
                    growing="true"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    class="customtable">

                     <columns >
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="EMPLOYEE ID"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="EMPLOYEE NAME"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="DEPT"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="STATE"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="DISTRICT"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="CITY"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                             <Text text="ADDRESS"/>
                         </Column>
                         <Column>
                             <Text text="ACTIONS"/>
                         </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                         <Text text="{EMPLOYEE_ID}"/>
                          <!-- add here on control per column --!>
                     </items>

        </Table>
```

or if your model had the name "CarService":
`items="CarService>/MyCarSet"`

Don't set growingThreshold. Ui5 will do this for you based on screen size/resolution.

**Update:**
Because "items" seams to be out of the blue and confusing, here an explanation on how to find it.

[sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table) is a subclass of a [sap.m.ListBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase). Under aggregation, you find `items` with a Cardinality of 0..n. This mean you can bind a datasource of many (lets called it here simplified an array) to this. You may add template in the items aggregation as well.

Comment: It’s missing the {} in the binding

Comment: actually I should include the controller.js of what I have tried(sorry) here, I am making an ajax call and binding as mentioned above, could you please look in to my controller (updated)

Answer (score 0):

In View.xml set growing and growingScrollToLoad on table to true:

```
    <Table
        id="table-id"
        noDataText="{i18n>initialNoDataText}"
        updateFinished="onTableUpdateFinished"
        growing="true"
        growingScrollToLoad="true">
            <columns>
                <Column hAlign="Left" width="10rem">
                    <Text text="{i18n>someText}"/>
                </Column>

                /* ...other columns... */

            </columns>
```

In xxx.controller.js

```
    onSearch: function () {

            /* ... contruct filters, columnListItem,... */

            this.byId("table-id").bindItems({
                path: "viewModel>/ExampleSet",
                parameters: { /* expand, select, etc... */ },
                filters: [new Filter("SomeProperty", FilterOperator.EQ, someControlValue)],
                template: oListItemTemplate, // your columnListItem
                templateShareable: false
        });
     }
```

With `growingScrollToLoad` when you scroll down the table and reach almost the bottom, it goes and fetches + binds the following rows.

Comment: May i know little about this too....`/* ... contruct filters, columnListItem,... */`

Comment: `columnListItem` is your template (var columnListItem = new sap.m.ColumnListItem... in your code).
`construct filters`  prepare your filters to pass to the filters propertie of the BindItems call. E.g. `var aFilters = [newFilter(...), new Filter(...)]` and then in bindItems `filters: aFilters`.

Comment: thanks sir, now I got it, I would try the same and would ask if got stuck